# An orthogonal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ with real eigenvalues is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form, orthogonal-matrices

I know there are two non trivial (i.e. if we solve these two cases the other cases are trivial) cases:

$\lambda_{1,2,3}=1$

and:

$\lambda_1=1,\lambda_{1,2}=-1$

I have been trying to use generalized eigenvectors and the Jordan Canonical and the fact that the JCF of matrix A can be rewritten as:

$\hat{A}=\hat{D}+\hat{N}$

Then I assume that $\hat{N}$ is not the zero matrix, but I don't know how/where to invoke the fact that A is orthogonal to get a contradiction. It feels like I have some of the pieces but not all of them...Any help would be greatly appreciated. This question is specific orthogonal matrices with the aforementioned eigenvalues. It would be helpful if this question was solved using definitoins for generalized eigenvectors and the JCF.

Comment: If someone could help prove this using the JCF that would be awesome as well

Comment: Using JCF here is like using a microscope to hammer a nail. Orthogonal matrices are *always* diagonalizable, it doesn't matter what the eigenvalues are.

Comment: I mean I'm only supposed to show it for the two aforementioned cases. My Prof said with what we've learned so far he thinks the only way we can prove it is with the JCF by assuming that there is a non zero nilpotent component to the  JCF of A. Also I'm only working in $\mathbb{R}^{3\cross3}$

Comment: Perhaps you should explain in the post what you learned so far. It is very odd that you can use JCF, a very advanced theorem, but not elementary properties of dot products and orthogonal matrices that directly follow from the definition $A^TA=I$. It is sometimes easier to prove general case instead of a contrived special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I think I figured it out. If A has a nontrivial JCF then we have an egeinvalue $\lambda\in\{-1,1\}$ and two nonzero vectors $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$Av=\lambda v+w$

$Aw=\lambda w$

These come from the first two columns of any nontrivial Jordan Block, and also get rid of the cases I was talking about earlier. They are also equivalent to assuming that $A$ is not diagonalizable. Dot the first equation with $w$, and use the fact that $A$ is orthogonal:

$\lambda(v,w)+(w,w)=(Av,w)=(v,A^Tw)=(v,A^{-1}w)$

From the second equation we have that:

$Aw=\lambda w $\iff$ A^{-1}w=\lambda^{-1}w=\lambda w$

Therefore we get:

$\lambda(v,w)+(w,w)=\lambda(v,w)$

which implies that

(w,w)=0

thus we have a contradiction, and A must be diagonalizable

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be your matrix, let $e_1$ be an eigenvector of $A$, and let $V=e_1^\perp$. Then, since $A$ is orthogonal, $A.V\subset V$. But $V$ is $2$-dimensional and the restriction of $A$ to $V$, seen as a linear map from $V$ to $V$, also only has real eigenvalues and it is also orthogonal. Therefore, it is diagonalizable: you ake an eigenvector $e_2$ of $A|_V$ and then, if $e_3$ is a non-nul vector of $V$ which is orthogonal to $e_2$, then $A.\operatorname{span}\{e_3\}\subset\operatorname{span}\{e_3\}$; in other words, $e_3$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. And then $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: You’re assuming that the result is true in dimension $2$. I think that this deserves a proof or at least a good argument considering the way the original question is posted. By the way, the result is true in any finite dimension. So the background here is induction.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Done.

Comment: Could you possibly explain this a little more thoroughly? I'm sorry I just dont really get what you're saying for some reason, it may be the notation.

Comment: @ChristopherLaFondJr. You will have to tell me what is that I wrote that you failed to understand.

Comment: Well right from the get go I don't know what you mean by $e_1^{\perp}$ or A. V. Also $A|_V$, and I am unfamiliar with with the terminology non-nul vector

Comment: Given a vector $v$, $v^\perp=\{w\in\Bbb R^3\mid v.w=0\}$. And$$A.V=\{A.v\mid v\in V\}.$$

Comment: what is A.v?  what is a non-null vector of V? a vector that isn't in the null space?

Comment: $A.v$ is what you get if you multiply your matrix $A$ with the vector $v$. And a non-null vector is a vector which is not $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: so then is v.w the same as the dot product? Also why is V 2 dimensional? Do you know of a way to do this proof using the JCF of A?

Comment: Yes, $v.w$ is the dot product of $v$ and $w$ (hence the dot). The space $V$ is $2$-dimensional because if $v\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, then $\dim v^\perp=n-1$. And I do not know what JCF is.

Comment: Jordan canonical form/Jordan normal form

Comment: I don't see how. If you are not interested in my answer, just say so.

Comment: I'm interested in it, I just don't understand it for some reason.